# Can it lead to problems while using the same Hibernate managed database for multiple projects?

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, jta

I'm using Wildfly with Hibernate and I will have two different projects accessing the same database. Each project has its own persistence.xml, but the datasources within the persistence.xml are the same. Currently I have one project with these datasources. This looks like this:

**Project A:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MyProjectPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myprojectDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="MyProjectLoggingUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myprojectDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The additional project's `persistence.xml` will look like this:

**Project B:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MyProjectLoggingUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myprojectDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The first project uses both JTA and RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions, so I can handle logging "manually". The second project uses JTA only since I only do logging operation there. Project A does CRUD operations, Project B does create operations only. Both projects run within the same Wildfly server. Is it possible that any problem, maybe with locking in database, transactions in Wildfly or whatever, could occur between project A and project B while accessing the same database with the same datasources from different projects as I do it? 
I don't think so, but I'm afraid that some 'side effects' could occur I don't know yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any problem, as Datasource is managed by jboss, it will allocate connection as per your configuration, locking can occure if you are using same row for processing from different projects but let database take care of that.

And there are different entities involved for not creating any problem like tho TCP connection is same/ shared sessions and transactions are diffrent for operation, spring and hibernate both are mature and best what they do, unless you messed with configurations ;), your looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that in principal you should not worry! BUT, since we are not dealing with magic and there is always an explanation when something does not work, the only case you should worry is a potential business coupling between the 2 applications and of course ends up in the data base. What I am trying to say, is that if Application1 which uses the same DB with Application2, performs things on entities that eventually are expected to be visible/ update for the logic on the other application, then yes there might be a chance that you will face some technical deadlocks (eventually pretty fine for a DB) but could be a problem on the business code level.

It is a matter of design and higher coupling, which happens to result in a technical coupling on the DB. I am not sure if I describe it correct, as a high level concern :)

Comment: You are right, but that is not going to happen. The only thing I do is just reading from a common table that both projects use, and just writing into the logging table that both projects use. There are no issues with business logic on these two operations.
(Actually both sub projects belong to one big project but they are different parts of it).